# AWS - S3 - Create bucket which is already existing - through CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Through AWS Console if you create a bucket if its already existing - console will not allow creating again.

But, through CLI it will allow you to create it again - when you execute make bucket command with the existing bucket - it just shows the success message.

It's really confusing, as doesn't show error in CLI. Confusing as different behaviors with two process.

Any idea why is this behavior and why CLI doesn't throw any error for the same?

Comment: share command you used

Comment: Please share the CLI command used.

Comment: Its normal command: "aws s3 mb s3://BUCKETNAME", whereas BUCKETNAME already exists.

Answer (score 3):

In a distributed system, when you ask to create most of the time it will upsert. Throwing error back is a costly process.

If you want to check whether bucket exists and if you have appropriate privileges use the following command.

```
aws s3api head-bucket --bucket my-bucket
```

**Documentation:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/head-bucket.html

> This operation is useful to determine if a bucket exists and you have
>   permission to access it.

Hope it helps.